# In Python, how can I swap an item with bigger left to right in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, swap

How to compare neighbor numbers in a list and swap them with each other? if the left number > the right one, eg `[6,8,7,2,9]` should be finally sorted as `[6, 7, 2, 8, 9]`

Comment: Please post your attempted *code* and where do you got stuck?  Does this require just *one-pass* only?  It seems so, otherwise, you may just go with built-in *sorted*.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list, and if that condition is met, swap the two numbers like this:

```
a = [6, 8, 7, 2, 9]

for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    if a[i] > a[i + 1]:
        a[i:i + 2] = a[i:i + 2][::-1]
    i += 1

print(a)
```